# Is there a difference in meaning between I like to + verb + something and I like verb + ing + something?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Ok, I never thought about this before, I always thought it was the same. I got the idea from the japanese SE that translating something as  I like to + verb + something is different thant I like verb + ing + something. May be I got it wrong. For example I like playing soccer is different than I like to play soccer? Does I like playing soccer give a sense that I like the general activity of playing soccer, and the second gives the idea that I want it to play it right now? Or they are just both exactly the same?

Comment: The item #5 of the last link seems to be asserting there is something true to what I wrote?

Comment: In the first link a person says it's the same exactly, and other says what I wrote here. Both are upvoted. What it would be the conclusion? If there is a nuance it's very subtle and not everybody catches it?